# How to sort QTableView ignoring case

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qt5, qtableview

I have a QTableView attached to QSqlTableModel. I want to give the users an option to sort the table at run time. The problem is I have values in both upper and lower case. So, when I do:

```
ui->tableView->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

It sorts the table as per column 0 but entries starting with 'a' are kept after entries starting with 'Z' for obvious reasons (because 'Z' = 90 and 'a' = 97 in ASCII). I want a way to sort the table using column 0 but ignoring the case

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: better now @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way i found was:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionAuthor_descending_triggered()
{
QSortFilterProxyModel *m = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

m->setSourceModel(model);
m->setSortCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

m->sort(1, Qt::DescendingOrder);

ui->tableView->setModel(m);
}
```